# How validation happens for multiple users using OAuth 1.0 token in WebAPI C#?

Tags: c#, oauth, access-token, webapi, oauth-1.0a

I have written logic in startup.cs to expire the token in every 10 minutes. but I worry when multiple users invoke the API different token will be generated for different users, then **how the state & token validity is maintained for different users**?
For example,

1. user1 get the token at 05:15 PM and this should expire at 05:25 PM - request after 5:25 should be rejected from user1
2. user2 get the token at 05:20 PM and this should expire at 05:30 PM - request after 5:30 should be rejected from user2

That means after 5:25 user1's operation should be revoked and user2 can use the token which is assigned to him and can do the operation till 5:30. How this is maintained and where it is managed?

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        var OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/tokenPath"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            Provider = new OauthProvider()
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    }
```